# Casting a Date matrix?

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame containing the following fields: a, b, c. a and b are identifiers and c is a Date. Not all identifier combinations have a date. There are some duplicate (a,b)s in the data. I only need the last c.

I want to create a table where the levels of a form the rows and the levels of b form the columns. If there is a c matching the levels of a and b, it should end up in the corresponding cell (t[a,b] = c). (I want to cluster the events with the table as a basis for a distance matrix.)

I tried doing the following:

```
f <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) > 0) {
    return(x[length(x)])
  }
  else {
    return(NA)
  }
}

m.df <- melt(df)
c.df <- cast(m.df, a ~ b, fun.aggregate = f)
```

This is otherwise OK, but cast somehow mangles the Dates into integers (14746 and whatnot). Why does this happen? Everything seems to be fine inside f. I can always convert the columns back into Dates, but this is rather strange - a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `?matrix`.  Specifically this paragraph in the Details section:

> ```
>  ‘as.matrix’ is a generic function.  The method for data frames
>  will return a character matrix if there is any
>  non-(numeric/logical/complex) column, applying ‘format’ to
>  non-character columns.  Otherwise, the usual coercion hierarchy
>  (logical < integer < double < complex) will be used, e.g.,
>  all-logical data frames will be coerced to a logical matrix, mixed
>  logical-integer will give a integer matrix, etc.
> ```

`Date` is not in that list, so you just get the underlying integer values.

Comment: The underlying type for `Date` appears to be `double`, not `integer`: `typeof(as.Date("1776-07-04"))` returns `"double"` (using R version 3.5.3).

Comment: @AnaNimbus it can be integer or double.  I said integer because I prefer to think of dates as whole numbers (I don't like the idea of "fractional" dates).